# How to disable UITextView area Highlight when clicked inside UITableView in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView Inside a custom UITableview. Whenever I try to click the tableView Cell, the UITextView Bounds gets Highlighted like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql6yZ.png). How can I prevent that highlighting? I've tried to disable `isUserInteractionEnabled`, `isEditable` and `isSelectable` inside `tableViewCell.swift` file but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an other UIViews in a cell content view to have a the same color as selection and highlight color then use this

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView! {
        didSet {
            textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `tableview.allowsSelecton = false` will not let me select any row in table view. My question was how can I not allow the UITextView to not get highlighted when clicked on the cell. The picture is attached in the question.

Comment: Kindly read my question again. I want to disable that white highlighting of UITextView when a cell is selected. I don't want to disable the selection of whole cell. The above can be achieved with simply `cell.selectionStyle = .none` which I don't want, as it will disable the highlight of whole cell. Refer to the picture I provided